# pip getting package from python's pypi instead of my own server

Tags: python, pip

For some reason I can't understand, pip is getting a package from the global's pypi instead of from my own server. My package, let's call it `foo`, has a dependency `bar`.

`pip search --index-url https://example.com/simple foo`

Returns my package.

`pip install --index-url https://example.com/simple foo`

Results in an error because it can't download `bar`.

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bar (from foo) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for bar (from foo)
```

`pip install --index-url https://example.com/simple --extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple foo`

ok so problem should be solved now right? it will get `foo` from my index and `bar` from pypi right? well... I'm afraid that's not the case. With this config, instead of downloading `foo` from my index, it downloads the `foo` package in pypi. Even after the installation, if I run `pip search foo` again, it will detect mine as `latest`, but the global one as `installed`

For testing's purpose, to have a clean baseline, I tried with `python:3.7-alpine`, same result.

As a workaround, I have setup the package's version as `yzt-0.1` so that I can specifically install `foo:yzt-0.1` and as it will not find it in global, it will install from my repo.

Comment: did you try the other way around? `pip install foo --extra-index-url https://example.com/simple`

Comment: The server usage looks correct to me; probably a python version/abi/platform mismatch. What files did you upload to your server and on what platform are you trying to install? Also, `pip install -vvv` will give you more info about what packages were found on which server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was the way pip works. If a version is not specified, it will always download the latest version, even though that means get it from the `extra` index while another one exists in the main index.

In my case, my package was `0.1`, but there was one with the same name in pypi with `0.1.1`, so as I was passing `--extra-index-url https://pypi.python.org/simple` to install the dependencies, `pip` was actually using that index to also download the `0.1.1` version.

So in summary, when you face a situation in which you have two different packages in different repositories but with the same name, you have two choices to ensure everything will work as expected:

- Change the package's name to something unique, like `username-packagename`.
- Add some id to the version so that you can install that specific version. Why the id? Because the package in pypi may have the same version as yours.

In my case, I prefer the second one because it's more cleaner. With the first one you need to `import username-packagename` which is uglier IMO.